# Using sass in Plunker?

Tags: sass, plunker

Super simple question sorry but is it possible to use sass in plunker

https://plnkr.co/

Comment: I don't think so, because it requires precompilation.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use with SCSS syntax. Just create a file with `.scss` extension and link from HTML with `.css` extension. Example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/dN5e8iY9S0idGPINdtry?p=preview

This behaviour is documented on the [Definitive Guide to Compilation on Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/suu7Yg/?show=preview&autoCloseSidebar). Another neat thing is that Plunker also supports relative `@import` directives (and even url-based `@import` directives) in case you want to split your work into different files.

Comment: This is good information but it doesn't seem to be working for a React SPA I'm putting together based on a React template.   :(